# How to customize output date format with jQuery UI calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I have a requirement to show the date in specific format. Month in date should show only four characters. i.e., Jan., Feb., Mar., Apr., May, June, July, Sept., Oct., Nov., Dec.. Is it possible to show month in this format using jQuery UI datepicker, maintaining it in date format?

Comment: You say `only four characters` and in your example it is `3 characters`

Comment: Four characters including period. But June, July and Sept should have four characters without period.

Comment: `Sept` includes period in your example and why are you taking four character from `september`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd M. yy" );
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function () {

    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept.", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var monthtext = months[$("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth()];
            if (monthtext.length == 4) {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd M yy");
            } else {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd M. yy");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd M. yy");

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"></p>
```

Comment: I tried this. But for June, July and Sept., four characters should show up which is not happening using this format.

Comment: @VinodKolla, Have updated my accordingly, Let me know if you still face any issue or you should mark it as answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate your datepicker method and do this callback:

```
$(".selector").datepicker(
 { monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ]}
);
```